# Append HTML code created by Node to HTML page

Tags: html, node.js, express

My goal here is to append a table that has resulted from the JS to the page in the ID called "henry". Also, should I even be doing the building of the table inside `app.get('/', function(req,res)`?

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    fabMgrWorkflows.listResources(dbClient,dcGrp,'fabMgr',
    function (err,dbClient,result){
        if(err) console.error(err);
        //result = JSON.stringify(result);
        /*
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,'\t'));
        */
        var addTable = "<table>";
        for(var attributename in result){
            addTable += "<tr>";
            addTable += "<td>" + attributename + "</td>";
            addTable += "<td>" + result[attributename] + "</td>";
            addTable += "</tr>";
        }
        addTable += "</table>";
        console.log(addTable);
        /*
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
        node.appendChild(addTable);
        document.getElementById("listtt").appendChild(node);
        console.log(addTable);
        */
        res.send(addTable);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Express comes with support for [jade(pug)](https://pugjs.org), which is a templating language that allows you to create html from data. You can render a template like so, where the first argument is the name of the template, and the second is the data to supply:

`res.render('your-template-name', {result})`

The [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) puts these files in /views by default.

The jade/pug file for your view might look something like this:

```
html
    head
        include head

    body
          #henry
              table
                  each attributename in result
                      tr
                          td= attributename
                          td= result[attributename]
```

If you need help with understanding how to set up a template engine for express, I recommend running the express-generator and inspecting the output.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate HTML in server side JS code, but instead pass your data to a view templating engine.

A great suggestion is [EJS](http://ejs.co/) since it uses normal HTML syntax with the ability to write some JS in between.
If you pass *result* to EJS, you could do something like:

```
<table>
  <% for (var attributename in result) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= attributename %></td>
      <td><%= result[attributename] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% } %>
</table>
```

For a comprehensive tutorial you could look [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application).

Comment: For EJS, do we need to organize the files in a certain way for it to work? Because I am looking at the tutorial and the first step is the file structure. I am wondering if thats needed?

Comment: You should place all of your views in a top-level views directory. Besides that the specified file structure in the tutorial is not mandatory, but it is recommended. You can see how the file to render is being specified as a parameter in the res.render() calls, so you could always use different paths if so desired.